# SharePoint as presentation layer for Azure SQL and Blob

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-storage, sharepoint-online

We currently have a simple requirement to present our users with a table of records. Each record has link to a PDF stored within Azure storage. We need to have our users be able to click on a record and be able to view (in line) the associated PDF.

We currently use SharePoint Online and cannot store the data within SharePoint itself (organisational policy).

Is it possible to create a SharePoint site/web part etc to do the above? We are scoping out options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SharePoint has several ways to do that.

Your best bet may be a custom list with a custom URL column for the link to the PDFs. Then you can insert a list web part on a page.

This approach works with modern pages and with classic pages.

If you use a classic interface, you could also create an out of the box links list, but that list type does not have a web part for the modern experience, so it will only work on classic pages.

Answer (score 0):

[SPFx webpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) can be inserted into modern page or classic page.

And you could call AD-secured APIs(custom service) in SPFx, so you could create a custom service host in Azure and consume from SPFx webpart.

[Connect to Azure AD-secured APIs in SharePoint Framework solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient)